# Confusion with the use of higher order function in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning how to create and use higher order functions in JS. I faced a bit of confusion with this code:

```
function elListMap(transform, list) {
    // list might be a NodeList, which doesn't have .map(), so we convert
    // it to an array.
    return [...list].map(transform);
}

function addSpinnerClass(el) {
    el.classList.add('spinner');
    return el;
}

// Find all the buttons with class 'loader'
const loadButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.loader');

// Add the spinner class to all the buttons we found.
elListMap(addSpinnerClass, loadButtons);
```

The question is Why don't we pass argument to addSpinnerClass when addSpinnerClass itself is passed to elListMap. I mean shouldn't we have `elListMap(addSpinnerClass(loadButtons), loadButtons);` instead of `elListMap(addSpinnerClass, loadButtons);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadButtons` is a list of elements. If you passed it to `addSpinnerClass` it would try to call the `classList.add()` method of that list of elements.

Since it is a *list of elements* and not **an element**, this would error and the program would stop.

If it didn't error, then you would pass the *return value* of `addSpinnerClass` (the value you passed into it: i.e. the list) as the first argument to `elListMap`.

`elListMap` would then pass that as the first argument to `map`. The first argument to `map` needs to be a function, but you would be passing a list of elements. So, again, it would error.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how is that possible addSpinnerClass needs an argument to work properly, but we pass nothing. What will addSpinnerClass return? undefined? SInce it returns el which we did not pass so expect undefined. Is that right?

Comment: @Dickens — `map` passes it an argument when it calls it.

Comment: behind the scenes we will have such code: [...loadbuttons].map(addSpinnerClass("Here will be put respective element")). Is that right?

Comment: @Dickens — No, because (again) that would *call* `addSpinnerClass` and pass its return value to `map` when you need to pass the `addSpinnerClass` function itself to `map`.